# How to define static files with extension in specific directory in google app engine app.yaml

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I have a problem in defining static files with extension within (specific directory).
this is my definition.

```
 - url: /files/(.*).(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS)
   static_files: \files\1.2
```

But no file is loaded. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
- url: /files/(.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS))$
   static_files: files/\1
   upload: files/.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS)$
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work and I tried to solve this problem by redirecting restricted directories into index file first and then allowing all directory as folow:

`- url: /(dir1|dir2|dir3)/.*
  script: index.php

- url: /(.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|GIF|png|PNG|jpg|JPG|ico|ICO|js|JS|css|CSS))`